# How to search for "OR" word inside a Field on ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I´m having a problem when I try to search into a field that stores the states acronyms.

I have the next query:

```
{
    "query": {
         "query_string": {
               "query": "field_state:'OR' AND type:incentive"
                 }
              }
}
```

And the problem comes when i try to get the results for the Oregon State (OR). For all the other states works but with this particular one is like the Elasticsearch takes the "OR" as a condition an retrieves all.

Is there a way to make this work????, i have try it with terms, prefix filters, and all with the same results.

Comment: Try just using an `AND` query with 2 conditions instead of the `query_string` query.

Comment: What analyzer are you using for this field? Are you sure this value is not being treated as a stop-word?

Comment: I`m not using any analyzer, and i also has not defined any stop-word. Is there a way to know if this is part of the default stop words??

Comment: @poncho1984 - "or" is a stop word in the StandardAnalyzer's default stop word set (might need to take a look in the lucene source to see the contents of `StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET`).

Comment: Is it possible to override that default values by just setting an Analyzer? or how it will be the best way to solve that????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to change the default analyzer away from the [Standard Analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/standard-analyzer/) (which does a bunch of stuff including filtering out english stop words like "or"). Here's an example using the [Simple Analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/simple-analyzer/) (which only lowercases):

```
curl -XPOST "http://MYHOST/MYINDEX/_close"
curl -XPUT "http://MYHOST/MYINDEX/_settings" -d '{
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "default": {
        "type": "simple"
      }
    }
  }
}'
curl -XPOST "http://MYHOST/MYINDEX/_open"
```

However if you **only** want to change the analyzer for `field_state`, you can update the mapping for that field directly:

```
curl -XPUT "http://MYHOST/MYINDEX/MYTYPE/_mapping" -d '{
  "MYTYPE": {
    "properties": {
      "field_state": {
        "analyzer": "simple",
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Just note that if you're using the simple analyzer, you may have to search for "or" instead of "OR":

```
curl -XPOST "http://MYHOST/MYINDEX/MYTYPE/_search" -d '{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "field_state:'or' AND type:incentive"
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: By default [Stop Token Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/stop-tokenfilter/) (which is used by the Standard Analyzer) uses a hard coded list of stop words which include the following:

    "a", "an", "and", "are", "as", "at", "be", "but", "by", "for", "if", "in", "into", "is", "it", "no", "not", "of", "on", "or", "such", "that", "the", "their", "then", "there", "these", "they", "this", "to", "was", "will", "with"